# KDE custom shortcut to run fish function

Tags: fish, kde-plasma

I'm trying to set ALT+F to run a fish function:

```
function nextSong
   set song (echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "path"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket | jq .data)

   echo 'playlist_next' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
   mv $song (fileSuffix $song s)
end
```

when I press ALT-F I get this error: "Timeout on server nextsong: Socket operation timed out"

It's not very clear whether the error is because KDE is not using fish to run the command or if the error is because it doesn't have the same permission that I have to run socat (???)

edit: it's also strange because in the error the s in nextsong is lowercase but in Custom Shortcuts the Action is definitely set to "nextSong" with capital "S"

I would think that if it is using bash then I would guess that it would silently fail or something like "can't find the command"

Comment: Show the exact command run when you hit alt-f -- you probably need `fish -c nextSong`

Comment: that worked!!! the "Socket operation timed out" error is worded very strange. I'm surprised that it was an error for BASH "command not found"

Comment: What does `type -à nextsong` return?

Comment: `$ type -a nextsong` 

`type: Could not find “nextsong”`

Comment: and `$ type -a nextSong` returns the function as defined above